# Calling some testActions make tests crash

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing, crash, cakephp-2.0

I am having problems with testing sometimes. The test is executed, i can even get the results of the action but the test doesn't show its green or red message telling me if the test run successfully or not. (28/28 test methods complete: 28 passes, 0 fails, 95 assertions and 0 exceptions...), the time, peak memory... etc.

For example. Only if i try to execute this test it crashes:

```
public function testGetHotVideo() {
    $result = $this->testAction("/posts/getHotVideo/");     
    $this->assertEquals($result, 'GoG_Tv5G17M');
}
```

It calls this method:

```
public function getHotVideo(){
    $video = $this->Post->getHotVideo();
    return $video[0][0]['video'];
}
```

And it returns the video string correctly. So it can even be printed on the test variable $result.

What's going on here?

## UPDATE

I have also notice it occurs the same when i call a method which redirects to some view. 
In this case, with the default delete created with Cake Bake:

```
public function delete($id = null){ 
        $this->Comment->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Comment->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid comment'));
        }
        if ($this->Comment->delete()) {         
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment deleted'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment was not deleted'));
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this SimpleTest (cakephp <= 1.3) or PHPUnit (>1.3)?

In case its SimpleTest you have to handle the redirects in your controller tests ([read Mark Storys article on controller testing](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/testing-cakephp-controllers-the-hard-way)). Basically you build a test class which inherits from the controller class you are testing and than you overwrite the redirect and some other methods (here some from the article):

```
class TestPostsController extends PostsController {
    ...     
    function redirect($url, $status = null, $exit = true) {
        $this->redirectUrl = $url;
    }   
    ...
}
```

than you use this modified controller in your test case.

With CakePHP 2 and PHPUnit I even had some issues with calling the header() function in some of the layouts, which broke the html structure and the css of the test-sides.

Comment: Its PHPUnit using CakePHP 2.0